# How To dynamically compile Code in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, roslyn, codedom

The nuget package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis' can not be use in .net standard environment. How To dynamically compile Code in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me in previous but after i implement i decided to use T4 template. Maybe you want to take a look T4 but this is for you; https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: CodeDOM has been abort in .Net Core.

Comment: I share it how to compile your own class so you can't compile .net core class in runtime because it's already compiled. You use it as .dll. I thought if you can override .net core methods in your own class you can compile. I think It can be only possible this way